# Why does a controller unit test start DI?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a Grails controller unit test which do nothing.
The controller has a field annotated with @Inject. 
The test crashes because of failed dependency injection.
But as far as I understand DI should not be used in the such kind of test.
Dependencies are setup manually in **given:** section of a test method.

So what do I do wrong? How to turn off DI in unit tests?

Here is my test:

```
@TestFor(MstarSearchController)
class MstarSearchControllerSpec extends Specification {
    void "test something"() {
        expect:
        3 == 3
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
class MstarSearchController {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    MstarSearchService mstarSearch
```

Command **grails test-app** crashes with the unsatisfied dependency.

```
test something(com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchControllerSpec)
 |
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchService com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchController.mstarSearch; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin.mockController_closure2(ControllerUnitTestMixin.groovy:185)
    at grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin.mockController(ControllerUnitTestMixin.groovy:193)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.invokeTargetMethod(MethodInvocation.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:49)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.invokeTargetMethod(MethodInvocation.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchService com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchController.mstarSearch; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aspect.dscadmin.MstarSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. It seemed that, through convention, based on the name of the test, Spock automatically instantiated a test object and attempted to inject all dependencies before I could do anything to prevent it. If you change your test's name to not correspond to the test class and remove the @TestFor annotation, you can instantiate the test object, instantiate a MstarSearch object, and assign the test object's mstarSearch manually in your setup without triggering @Autowired.